# Book about an unbreakable code

Tags: story-identification

I read a book about 5 years ago about a cube with information that's encrypted with an unbreakable code, and the cube gets stolen from a young genius.

I think there are elves, and a dwarf who farts extensively.

In the end the protagonist turns out to be a hologram and the thieves are trapped inside their own top grade security.

And I distinctly remember the protagonists using a human finger to get through some gel-pad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is "[The Eternity Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis_Fowl:_The_Eternity_Code)" by Eoin Colfer.

> *Most humans don't know about them, mostly because of the IT specialist
> named Foaly. The Centaurs' technology, and therefore the technology of
> the fairies, is about a century ahead of ours. Anyway, one more
> character must not be forgotten: Mulch Diggums. **This hairy lad is a
> dwarf with a wide range of abilities including so-called gas
> explosions, which are more or less massive farts,** and extremely
> sensitive hair that can pick up vibration, and even sense danger. So
> much for the characters. Why don't we start with the actual content of
> the book now.*
>
> ...
>
> *With Spiro in possession of the Cube, the fairy folk is in great
> danger, so Artemis asks his fairy friends for help. Luckily young
> Artemis has locked the cube with an unbreakable code, an eternity
> code. The time you require to break this code is said in the name, but
> with Spiro's possibilities quite a bit less.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Book report: Artemis Fowl](http://www.altenforst.de/index.php/56-faecher/englisch2/366-book-report-artemis-fowl)</sup></sub>

Comment: Beat me to it.  And yes, using the finger to get through some kind of lock did factor in.